# When Checkbox is selected particular columns should be enabled

Tags: javascript, checkbox, onclick, isenabled

I have tried few examples to enable particular columns(text box,check box) alone when checkbox is checked.But nothing is working.I have included my code here

```
function enable() 
{

    if (document.getElementById("MaincheckboxId").checked == true)
    {
        document.getElementById("column1Id").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("column2id").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("subcheckboxId").disabled = true;

    }
}
```

Here, when Main Checkbox is checked, column 1 and Column 2 should be enabled. Sub Checkbox should be disbaled.Please let me know what am i missing.

Comment: What's causing `enable()` to be ran?

Comment: Hi Jack,When the Main check box is clicked,enable() should run

Comment: It should run, or it does run?

Comment: It should run. But i am seeing no changes in screen.

Comment: Are you able to verify that it is being called? Add `console.trace()` to the top of the `enable()` function and post the output.

Comment: I have actually written this code in JSP(the checkbox and columns are written in jsp) file under script tags.In order to initiate function calling i am using onclick="enable;" . But Netbeans is warning no to use onclick for check box. Is this could be problem?

Comment: Right, but is it actually calling it or not?

Comment: I think no.I tried document.write();inside the function. It is not getting reflected.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work. Based on your comment, problem might be incorrect calling of enable(). Change your HTML from `onclick="enable;"` to `onclick="enable()"` should fix it.